Expected number of rounds that the first player wins the game
A and B alternately keep rolling a fair dice. The person who gets a six first wins the game. Given that player A wins, what is the expected number of rounds that A plays?
I know that the probabilty for A to win the game is 6/11. But I am not sure about how to calculate the expected number of rounds A plays given A wins.

First, let us try to guess what the answer approximately is. Obviously, there will be on average $6$ rolls before the first $6$ appears. So if we know that the first player is bound to win, it will happen around his $3$-rd roll. Probably, a bit greater. Because this first appearance of $6$ could have happened on the second players’s roll.
Here are two approaches to solving this exactly.
(1) Via the recurrence equation. First, let us notice that that the expected number of rounds if the first player wins equals the expected number of rounds if the second player wins. Because these two numbers both equal to the expected number of rounds that the game continues (round being two rolls of both players). This expectation satisfies the following equation:
$$E= \left(\frac16+\frac56\cdot\frac16\right)\cdot1 + \left(\frac56\cdot\frac56\right)\cdot\left(E+1\right).$$
Indeed, the number of rounds equals $1$ with probability $\frac16$ (the first player rolls $6$ immediately) plus $\frac56\cdot\frac16$ (if the second player wins with his first roll). Or it increases by $1$ if they both miss, which happens with probability $\frac56\cdot\frac56$.
Solving the equation, we get $$E=\frac{36}{11}.$$
(2) Via the series calculation. We deal here with the conditional expectation. Let $Y$ be the random variable, equal to the number of the winning player. Possible values are $1$ or $2$. As you correctly state $$P(Y=1)=\frac6{11}.$$
Let $X$ be the random variable, equal to the number of the rounds the first played made. We are wondering, what is $$\mathbb E[X\mid Y=1] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\cdot P(X=k \mid Y=1).$$
Since every player made $k-1$ rolls before the winning roll, we have $$P(X=k \mid Y=1)= \frac{P(X=k, Y=1)}{P(Y=1)}=\frac{\frac16\cdot\left(\frac56\right)^{2(k-1)}}{\frac6{11}}.$$
Hence, $$\mathbb E[X\mid Y=1]=\frac{11}{36}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \cdot\left(\frac56\right)^{2(k-1)} .$$
Let us calculate $$S= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k \cdot\left(\frac56\right)^{2(k-1)} .$$
We have $$\left(\frac56\right)^2\cdot S = \sum_{k=1}^\infty(k-1) \cdot\left(\frac56\right)^{2(k-1)} .$$
Subtracting the last two equalities, we get: $$\left(1-\frac{25}{36}\right)\cdot S = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^{k-1} = \frac1{1-\frac{25}{36}}.$$
Therefore, $$S= \left(\frac1{1-\frac{25}{36}}\right)^2 =\left(\frac{36}{11}\right)^2. $$
Finally, $$\mathbb E[X\mid Y=1]=\frac{11}{36}\cdot S= \frac{11}{36} \cdot\left(\frac{36}{11}\right)^2= \frac{36}{11}.$$

Thank you so much! This is very helpful!

I got a different answer using a recurrence method. My logic is the same but surely I don't understand why $E=(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6}⋅\frac{1}{6})⋅1+(\frac{5}{6}⋅\frac{5}{6})⋅(E+1)$. Shouldn't it be: $E=\frac{1}{6}⋅1+(\frac{5}{6}⋅\frac{5}{6})⋅(E+1)$ since we are conditioning on the fact that A wins. So A wins in 1 round with probability $\frac{1}{6}$ otherwise we can think of the game as restarting if both A and B don't get 6 in the first round which happens with prob $(\frac{5}{6})^2$ and we add on 1 round as well. That would give an answer of $\frac{31}{11}$
